# Wide FOV and Large Baseline Fisheye stereo cameras rectification

Tags: camera-calibration, fisheye, stereoscopy

Iam working on Fisheye stereo cameras, I can't Rectify the cameras for stereo correspondence due to the presence of vegetation and the large baseline between the cameras which make the task particularly challenging. The FOV is 210 degrees and baseline is 0.59m I posted Left and Right image of the same scene with the cameras,
[Left Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqo6i.jpg) [Right Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32f8v.jpg)

I've tried OpenCV-Fisheye model and openCv-Omnidirectional model, none of them worked, the output images were not rectified.
Should the Omnidirectional model work? 
Is it even possible to calibrate the cameras together?